# Alternative to LIMIT 1 to extract a date range plus first entry before and after?

Tags: sql, sqlite, union, limit

Basically, I want to select within a range + 1 entry after and 1 entry before.

I tried like this:

```
SELECT DateTime, value FROM ReadingGlucoseBlood WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2011-01-21 00:00:00' AND datetime('2011-01-21 00:00:00', '+24 hours') 
UNION 
SELECT DateTime, value FROM ReadingGlucoseBlood WHERE DateTime < '2011-01-21 00:00:00' LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT DateTime, value FROM ReadingGlucoseBlood WHERE DateTime > datetime('2011-01-21 00:00:00', '+24 hours') LIMIT 1
ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```

But it turns out I can only have one LIMIT at the very end of a compound SELECT statement.. so how do I achieve this effect? (using sqlite btw)

Comment: If the target date is 2011-01-21, will the date before always be one day before and one day after in perfect sequence (e.g. 2011-01-20, 2011-01-22) or is it the case that there are gaps in the date sequence so that, using our example date, the "before date" might be 2011-01-05 or something?

Comment: there could be skipped dates since i'm tracking events rather than dates specifically (typically there would be 3+ events per day). just want to be able to compare the first event of the day to the most recent preceding event and same with the following one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subquery the LIMITs to limit their scope

```
SELECT DateTime, value FROM ReadingGlucoseBlood WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2011-01-21 00:00:00' AND datetime('2011-01-21 00:00:00', '+24 hours') 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DateTime, value FROM ReadingGlucoseBlood WHERE DateTime < '2011-01-21 00:00:00'
ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1
) X
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DateTime, value FROM ReadingGlucoseBlood WHERE DateTime > datetime('2011-01-21 00:00:00', '+24 hours')
ORDER BY DateTime ASC LIMIT 1
) Y
ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```

Comment: There could be alternatives, but using LIMIT 1 properly is really the fastest choice.

Comment: that is longer than i was expecting to be necessary!.. but length is not really an issue. thank you.